# How to make an async Task continue with next task after first one completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How to continue with next task after the dependent one completed? Will `Task.ContinueWith()` help? If not, how can I effectively handle the below case without clubbing the functions into a single function? Let's say there are 4 async functions:

```
async Task<string> Func1(string a){}
async Task<string> Func2(string returnedStringFromFunc1 ){}
async Task<string> Func3(string b){}
async Task<string> Func4(string returnedStringFromFunc3){}

Task tsk1 = func1("abc");
Task tsk3 = func3("efg");
await tsk1; // In case tsk3 is completed early, flow is waiting here.
    // Instead I could have started tsk4. 
Task tsk2 = func2(tsk1.Result);
await tsk3;
Task tsk4 = func4(tsk3.Result);
```

Comment: What issue did you encounter with ContinueWith()? It seems to advertise well what its doing and it seems to fit your case.

Comment: This seems like an xy problem., it could be you need to just await

Comment: @SnowGroomer How can i pass the input of previous task in ContinueWith- I couldn't find any example in the web.

Comment: @user1066231 I have posted a possible solution with ContinueWith as an answer - comments are to short to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dropping in these extremely helpful extension methods:

```
public static class TaskEx
{
    public static async Task<R> Select<T, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, R> s)
    {
        var t = await task;
        return s(t);
    }
    public static async Task<R> SelectMany<T, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<R>> k) => await k(await task);
    public static async Task<R> SelectMany<T, U, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<U>> k, Func<T, U, R> s)
    {
        var t = await task;
        var u = await k(t);
        return s(t, u);
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    Task<string> q1 =
        from x in Func1("abc")
        from y in Func2(x)
        select y;

    Task<string> q2 =
        from x in Func3("efg")
        from y in Func4(x)
        select y;

    string r1 = await q1;
    string r2 = await q2;

    Console.WriteLine(r1);
    Console.WriteLine(r2);
}

Task<string> Func1(string a) => Task.FromResult(a);
Task<string> Func2(string c) => Task.FromResult($"{c}!");
Task<string> Func3(string b) => Task.FromResult(b);
Task<string> Func4(string d) => Task.FromResult($"{d}!");
```

I get the following:

```
abc!
efg!
```

Comment: Reactive programming for the win!

Comment: @PauloMorgado - It's not reactive. It's simply implementing the correct overloads for the LINQ operators to make tasks work.

Answer (score 5):

You could use two separate functions, even local functions, to combine the tasks:

```
async Task<string> Flow1(string input)
{
    var r1=await func1(input);
    var r2=await func2(r1);
    return r2;
}

async Task<string> Flow2(string input)
{
    var r1=await func3(input);
    var r2=await func4(r1);
    return r2;
}

var task1=Flow1("abc");
var task2=Flow2("efg");

await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) and depending on which task completed start the next one and then wait for the last one to complete.

```
Task tsk1 = func1("abc");
Task tsk3 = func3("efg");
Task tsk2 = null, tsk4 = null;

var completed = await Task.WhenAny(new [] {tsk1, tsk3});
if (completed == tsk1)
{
  tsk2 = func2(tsk1.Result);
  await tsk3;
  tsk4 = func4(tsk3.Result);
}
else
{
  tsk4 = func4(tsk3.Result);
  await tsk1;
  tsk2 = func2(tsk1.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more conventional way of using [Enigmativity's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835136/how-to-make-a-async-task-continue-with-next-after-first-one-completed-c-sharp/67835701#67835701) quite handy `SelectMany` extension method for tasks:

```
Task<string> combo12 = Func1("abc").SelectMany(async x => await Func2(x));
Task<string> combo34 = Func3("efg").SelectMany(async x => await Func4(x));
await Task.WhenAll(combo12, combo34); // Await the completion of both workflows
string result12 = await combo12;
string result34 = await combo34;
```

The `SelectMany` extension method:

```
public static async Task<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(
    this Task<TSource> task, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> function)
{
    return await function(await task);
}
```

The code could be simplified by [eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) in the asynchronous delegate, like this:

```
Task<string> combo12 = Func1("abc").SelectMany(x => Func2(x));
Task<string> combo34 = Func3("efg").SelectMany(x => Func4(x));
```

...or even like this:

```
Task<string> combo12 = Func1("abc").SelectMany(Func2);
Task<string> combo34 = Func3("efg").SelectMany(Func4);
```

You could do the same thing without the `SelectMany` operator, but it becomes rather awkward:

```
Task<string> combo12 = ((Func<Task<string>>)(
    async () => await Func2(await Func1("abc"))))();
Task<string> combo34 = ((Func<Task<string>>)(
    async () => await Func4(await Func3("efg"))))();
```

If you want to learn more about the theory behind the `SelectMany` operator, you may find this article interesting: [Tasks, Monads, and LINQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-monads-and-linq/) by Stephen Toub